# ASP.NET Forms Authentication with per session/page API token

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, rest, forms-authentication

Let me first start by saying that I realize that this is very similar to many other questions about service access control but I can't seem to find one response that is relevant on all of the points below, so I am asking (possibly) again.

Some background:
I am building a web application with .NET that is protected by a custom forms authentication implementation. This same app (within the same domain) needs to leverage several REST services related to data management from within JavaScript/jQuery as many of the app's functions are not well suited to post back use in the forms.

I am trying to determine the most secure way to implement access control for the REST service based on the authentication done server side when the app was first accessed.

Here is an example use case for what I am describing:

1. user logs into asp.net site using forms authentication and upon successful authentication the user is taken to the landing page of the application
2. the user chooses to access a page at ~/Users.aspx from a link on the landing page, which forms auth allows based on the cookie created by the authentication in step 1
3. users.aspx loads some basic HTML elements, like an empty table and a hidden field that contains a token (GUID) generated at page load.  The token in the hidden field is used by JavaScript to access a REST service that retrieves data to populate the table. The token is stored in a database with a pre-defined expiration.
4. when the REST service is called with the token it is checked for expiration and used to determine the user making the call and provide authorization to the data being accessed from the database, if the user is authorized to access/update the data the service performs the requested service operation, extends the expiration on the token, and returns a response.

I know that the token would be visible to someone sniffing the request/response on the network unless SSL is used to encrypt the transmission, so SSL is used to counter this.

My question is:

1. Are there other attacks that the service would be vulnerable to?
2. is there a better way to handle authorization and user identification for the REST service based on the server side login other than a statically assigned token for the service?  It seems to me that the statically assigned user token would be less secure since it would give endless access to the service if it were obtained by a malicious user.
3. assuming the answer to #2 is no, is there a better way to transmit the token to the client and store it there for the life of the page use knowing that it needs to be accessible from JavaScript/jQuery?